# Use global temp recordset for exchange info inside module vba

Tags: vba, global-variables, recordset

I want to develop a function that executes all queries to database and store the result in a global recordset for use it in others functions, but when function or sub ends, the global recordset gets empty (out of scope). How can I fix this?

Module content:

```
Global rsResultado As ADODB.Recordset

Sub main()
    sql = "query works ok, I get data"
    realizarConsulta (sql)
    Debug.Print "Check result: " & rsResultado.Fields(0) 'Here I lost data setted in function
End Sub

Public Function realizarConsulta(sql As String) As Recordset
    conectarBD
    Debug.Print "SQL Ejecutada -->" & sql
    Set rsResultado = New ADODB.Recordset

    rsResultado.Open sql, Conn
    'Set realizarConsulta = rs
    'Set rsResultado = rs

    Do While Not rsResultado.EOF
        Debug.Print "Registro: " & rsResultado.Fields(0)
        rsResultado.MoveNext
        'Here I can see the content of the global recordset
    Loop

    'rs.Close
    Conn.Close
End Function
```

Is there any way to fix this issue? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have a global recordset in a module, I want to set (put info on it) that recordset inside a function or sub, and then use it outside of that function (or sub). But when gets out the function (or sub), that recordset is out of context. How could it be if it's a global variable which value is setted inside a function, it should keep the data outside de function (or sub).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global `Recordset` gets empty because you close connexion inside a `Function`,the `Recordset` spent all records after the while loop , and you must set recordset from `Function` :

1- Set the `Recordset` object  in main sub like : `Set rsResultado = realizarConsulta(sql)`

2- Init the `Recordset` object with `rsResultado.MoveFirst`

3-Set Function object inside Function with : `Set realizarConsulta = rsResultado`

4-Do not close the connection object `Conn`

```
Sub main()
    '..
    Set rsResultado = realizarConsulta(sql)
    rsResultado.MoveFirst
    Debug.Print "Check result: " & rsResultado.Fields(0)
End Sub

Public Function realizarConsulta(sql As String) As Recordset
    conectarBD
    Debug.Print "SQL Ejecutada -->" & sql
    Set rsResultado = New ADODB.Recordset

    rsResultado.Open sql, Conn

    Do While Not rsResultado.EOF
        Debug.Print "Registro: " & rsResultado.Fields(0)
        rsResultado.MoveNext
    Loop

    Set realizarConsulta = rsResultado

    'rs.Close
    'Conn.Close
End Function
```

Comment: I tried that but still getting the same result. Once i get out the function, the global recordset has no data. In variable inspector I see the value: "Out of context". Thanks for your answer

Comment: I change the answer, please test it ? it works well for me.

Comment: That's the answer. I was failing because I was closing the Database connection. I tried it and it worked!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the connection to the database to be `Global`. Otherwise your `RecordSet` gets reset when the connection is closed. So, if you add

`Global conDataBaseConnection As ADODB.Connection`

Then it should work (tested on my system).

<sub>Since I do not see your `ADODB.Connection` declaration I just named it by example. Obviously, you'll have to change the code to match your programming.</sub>

Comment: I was mistaking because I closed BD connection, and when you do that, you lose any data stored in a recordset which depends on that connection. Thanks for your time anyway.